# How to resolve 401 Unauthorized failures on intranet pages with IIS and Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, ntlm, intranet

I'm attempting allow/restrict website intranet users access based on Active Directory permissions.

I thought we'd reached our objective (authentication without domain sign-on prompt) until I discovered that pages (or even text files) accessed via our popular browsers Chrome/IE11/Firefox result in three requests for the same asset, two which of which fail with a 401 response code.

Capturing this with Charles Proxy [it would look as such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRqEh.png):

1. `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
   HTTP Error 401. The requested resource requires user authentication`
2. `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 
   401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials`
3. `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

The specifics of these requests/responses can be seen here:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3iBiGqHc

**These happen in rapid succession,** as if the browser is attempting retires. The resolution isn't sticky, and the browser will continue to request files in triplicate.

Are we missing a configuration setting somewhere?

PHP 5.6.9, IIS 7.5, Windows Server 2008 R2 SE SP1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is just how it works.

The 401 response is what tells the browser to provide credentials in scenarios other than mutual certificate authentication over TLS.

Comment: Triplicate requests would be most unfortunate; hopefully this isn't the case --

Comment: Found [this graphic](http://www.scip.be/ImagesScreenshots/ArticleWebAPI%20-%20WIA2.png) that might very well speak to your point: (from [http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET38](http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET38))

Comment: Yeah that is how it works.